# Show that $p+q-1 \le r \le min(p,q)$

Tags: probability, proof-verification, random-variables, bernoulli-numbers

I have the following problem.

> Let X and Y be Bernoulli random variables with parameters p and q,
>   respectively. The random variable Z = XY also takes only values 0 and
>   1 and hence is a Bernoulli random variable with some parameter r. Show
>   that $$p+q-1 \le r \le min(p,q) $$
>
> Hint: Use the fact that Z = 0 when X = 0 or Y = 0.

Any hint, suggestion or idea is welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: The hint tells you that $P(Z=0) \le P(X=0 \cup Y=0)$, which will help with the left inequality. Another hint is that $X = 1$ when $Z = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if an event $A$ is contained in an other event $B$, then $\mathbb{P}(A) \leq \mathbb{P}(B)$.

Note that if $XY=1$, then $X=1$. Hence $\{XY=1\} \subset \{X=1\}$. What does this tell you about $p$, $q$ and $r$?

You also know that $\{XY=0\} \subset \{X=0\} \cup \{Y=0\}$ (why?). What can you deduce from this?